# Looping through date in R loses format

Tags: r, loops, date, lubridate

This has been frustrating me. Even with `lubridate` I can't get dates to maintain their type when I loop over them. For example:

```
require(lubridate)
yearrange = ymd(20110101) + years(seq(4))
yearrange
#[1] "2012-01-01 UTC" "2013-01-01 UTC" "2014-01-01 UTC" "2015-01-01 UTC"
class(yearrange)
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

However, if I try to loop through years (creating a separate plot for each year in my data set): **I lose the formatting of the year, and would have to re-cast the data**

```
for (yr in yearrange) { show(yr) }
#[1] 1325376000
#[1] 1356998400
#[1] 1388534400
#[1] 1420070400
```

If I loop though specifying indices, I get date objects back:

```
for (i in seq(length(yearrange))) { show(yearrange[i]) }
#[1] "2012-01-01 UTC"
#[1] "2013-01-01 UTC"
#[1] "2014-01-01 UTC"
#[1] "2015-01-01 UTC"
```

Is there an easy way to avoid the indexed option, without using `foreach`, or is that the only way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
for (yr in as.list(yearrange))  { show(yr) }
```

I think `for (yr in yearrange)` coerces `yearrange` into a vector and `POSIXct` is not one of the supported types that vector coerces into.

Comment: Thanks. This solves my problem. I am also going to implement it as a function instead of a `for` loop, so will probably take advantage of @thelatemail solution too

Answer (score 2):

`lapply` doesn't seem to have the same problem, e.g.:

```
for (x in yearrange) plot(1, main=x)
#Main title = 1420070400
lapply( yearrange, function(x) plot(1, main=x) )
#Main title = 2015-01-01
```

Comment: Yes, because it uses `as.list(X)`, where `X=yearrange`. You can see it when you inspect the source code of `lapply`.

Comment: I'm going to make a function to generate my plots instead of looping so will use your answer as well, although the other one more directly solved my frustration. Thanks.